# Masonry Grid Collapsed On Load

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry, masonry

Masonry grid works but the images are collapsing on top of each other and not loading correctly.

We can not get it to work using the jquery or js script tags so we added the html way

```
<h2>Recent Resin Bound Driveway Installations</h2>
        <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }'>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resindriveway1.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/product-resin-bound2.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
           <img src="img/resin-1.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin4.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin5.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin1.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway"></a>
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin-new1.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin-new4.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway"></a>
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin-new2.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin3.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway"></a>
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin-new5.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway"></a>
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin2.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway"></a>
        </div><!--ends four-->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/resin8.jpg" alt="Resin Bound Driveway">
        </div><!--ends four-->
      </div>
```

loading the masonry script file in the head but makes no difference as was still broken when loaded in the footer too.

Comment: If your using the current version of Masonry (4.2.1), imagesLoaded is a separate script you need download at [imagesloaded.desandro.com](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) and install on you page. It is no longer part of masonry. Adding the function without the script will obviously not work.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough karma to post as a comment:

Are you using the masonry provided "imagesLoaded" function?
This will wait for all images to be loaded before applying the masonry

Comment: added this in and made no difference